# How would I store OpenCV rotatedRect's in a database

Tags: database, postgresql, opencv

I have a need to store data from an openCV rotatedRect into a database and also be able to search through them. In short, a rotated rectangle in openCV consists of:

- a set of four points representing the four corners of the rectangle
- the angle the rect is rotated at
- the center point of the rect
- the bounding box of the rotated rect

I'm not sure if this is more than one question, but I think they relate to each other nicely:

1. how would I represent this in PostgreSQL? One record will consist of (among other fields) several hundred rotated rect's in a sequential fashion. Does this look sensible?

   ```
   // the rotated rect type
   CREATE TYPE rotated_rect AS {
       angle real,
       points point ARRAY[4],
       center point,
       bounding_box box,
       width real,
       height real
   };

   // the item that will have several hundred rotated_rects
   CREATE TABLE foo {
       ...,
       rotated_rects rotated_rect[],
       ...
   };
   ```
2. How would I then go about searching this data? I'd like to be able to compare one list of rotated rect's with those stored in the database for each record - quite possibly just the center-point of each rotated rect at this stage - and pick out the record/s which either match exactly, or are the closest in position. Would this require PostGIS for spatial data? Or would I have to read all the records into memory and search position manually?

EDIT: Added a stab at a type for postgresql.